# How to retrieve value of multiple <p> tags in multiple iframes in a single web page?

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

We have a page that has multiple iframes. Each of the iframes has multiple < p > tags having no id. We have to retrieve the value of the multiple tags (id less) from the multiple iframes to feed the MySQL database using PHP. We know we have to use jQuery, but not exactly sure, how..are there any other ways?

It would be great if you could guide us how to go about it..

Comment: Multiple frames, at the same domain? We're not offering free tuturials, we're only answering specific programming-related questions. See [faq].

Answer (score 0):

To get the values of the `<p>` tags with jquery from iframes you can use this code:

```
$("iframe").contents().find("p").each(function(){
      var p_content = $(this).text();
});
```

I think this should do it.
Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

The process would basically go like this:

- Get all the `<iframe>` elements
- Cycle through them and get all of their `<p>` elements
- Cycle through *them* and get all of their values

There's probably a super efficient way to do it with jQuery, but here's how I'd construct it, just off the top of my head:

```
var values = [];
function pEach(i, p) {
    values[values.length] = p.innerHTML;
}
function iframeEach(i, frame) {
    $(frame).contents().find('p').each(pEach);
}
$('iframe').each(iframeEach);
```

At the end of that, the `values` array will contain all of the `innerHTML` values of all the `<p>` tags in all the page's frames.

Once you have the values in some array, you can just make a simple POST request like so:

```
values = values.join('|'); // just serializing the data...
$.post('saveToDB.php', values);
```

Then just have your PHP page <del>split</del> explode the data and insert into the database however you like.